# How to navigate to character position in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a program that retrieves the character position of certain key operations in a Java file (i.e. a variable is declared 2301 characters from the top of the file). I want to go directly to this character position while viewing the file in Eclipse. I'm able to do this [using a text editor like Notepad++,](https://superuser.com/questions/1277472/how-to-navigate-to-position-in-notepad) but I want to do it within the Eclipse IDE for easier use during development.

How can I navigate to a position when the file is opened using the Eclipse IDE?

Comment: In what context? Do you mean from inside an installed Eclipse plug-in?

Comment: The Java editor UI only supports going to a line number, not a character position, code in a plug-in can position at a character offset.

Comment: The Emacs+ plugin allows you to provide a "prefix argument" (technically, the "universal argument") to many functions, which it interprets in the context of the function being executed. If your cursor is at the top of the file and you provide "2000" as the universal argument, and then execute the binding for "forward-character", it will execute that function 2000 times.